# Glide Image request : Does downloadOnly check the cache before downloading only?

Tags: android, android-glide

I am making a request like below, but i want to know if downloadOnly checks the cache for the image first?

```
FutureTarget<File> future = Glide.with(applicationContext)
    .load(yourUrl)
    .downloadOnly(500, 500);
File cacheFile = future.get();
```

My main issue is that the image in yourUrl is already loaded in the cache, and i need a synchronous way to retrieve the image from the cache in a background thread.

The code above works, but i need to know if there is a cache check before downloadOnly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After turning on verbose logging for Glide, I was able to see exactly what was going on when the image was being called, while DecodeJob mostly fetched from cache in less than 10ms, at times it fetched the data again, not sure maybe from disk or over the wire.

So ultimately i had to check only the cache with a custom StreamModelLoader that throws an exception if trying to go over the wire, and on a cache MISS then use the default flow.

```
private final StreamModelLoader<String> cacheOnlyStreamLoader = new StreamModelLoader<String>() {
        @Override
        public DataFetcher<InputStream> getResourceFetcher(final String model, int i, int i1) {
            return new DataFetcher<InputStream>() {
                @Override
                public InputStream loadData(Priority priority) throws Exception {
                    throw new IOException();
                }

                @Override
                public void cleanup() {

                }

                @Override
                public String getId() {
                    return model;
                }

                @Override
                public void cancel() {

                }
            };
        }
    };

FutureTarget<File> future = Glide.with(progressBar.getContext())
                    .using(cacheOnlyStreamLoader)
                    .load(url).downloadOnly(width, height);

            File cacheFile = null;
            try {
                cacheFile = future.get();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();  //exception thrown if image not in cache
            }

            if(cacheFile == null || cacheFile.length() < 1) {
                //didn't find the image in cache
                future = Glide.with(progressBar.getContext())
                        .load(url).downloadOnly(width, height);

                cacheFile = future.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //wait 3 seconds to retrieve the image
            }
```

Comment: So what was the result?